# Using foreach with Variable + Index combination

Tags: php, loops, for-loop, foreach

Following my [unsolved question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34907553/auto-generate-index-number-for-variables-inside-same-table-row-for-each-row),
I'm trying to figure how to use `foreach`

How can I make this kind of code:

```
$m1="mbob";
$m2="mdan";
$m3="mbill";

$a = array('bob', 'dan', 'bill');

$i = 1; /* for illustrative purposes only */

foreach ($a as $v) {
    echo "\$a[$i] => $v.\n";
    echo $m[$i];
    $i++;
}
```

To output this result:

```
$a[1] => bob.
mbob
$a[2] => dan.
mdan
$a[3] => bill.
mbill
```

I'm getting the error:

> Undefined variable: m

But I'm trying to output the `m1,m2,m3` variables, not just `m`.

Comment: it's not a repost, it's a related question.

Comment: Are you unable to make the $m values into an array? Because what you are asking for is pretty bad practice, arguably.

Comment: @Fred-ii- - No... that's your assumption, under the guise of logic.

Comment: @HC_ I don't want to make it into an array, if you'll take a look at my previous question you'll see that an array wouldn't fit, as I'll have to create dozens of arrays and it will be a mess to change values when needed.

Answer (score 1):

That's something I've never done but you may try and give it a shot:

```
echo $('m' . $i);
```

That's similar to function invocations where you construct the function name dynamically through a string, but I don't know if it works with local variables as well.

Answer (score 1):

Here is code that works, but I would not recommend it. I would recommend just storing your `$m` values in an array.

```
<?php
    $m1="mbob";
    $m2="mdan";
    $m3="mbill";

    $array = array('bob', 'dan', 'bill');
    $i = 1;
    foreach ($array as $value) {
        echo "\$a[$i] => $value.\n";
        echo '<br>';
        echo ${"m".$i};
        echo '<br>';
        $i++;
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, $m is not an array. There is a way to create variable variable names which appears to be what you are trying to do, but simpler is to create $m as an array:

```
$m =array("mbob","mdan","mbill");

$a = array('bob', 'dan', 'bill');

$i = 1; /* for illustrative purposes only */

foreach ($a as $v) {
    echo "\$a[$i] => $v.\n";
    echo $m[$i];
    $i++;
}
```